# Doctrine update model with oneToMany fields

Tags: database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Couldn't get much help from the World Wide Wide Wide Web ...

The situation is:

- My model has two manyToMany fields and one oneToMany field.
- When I update the model, doctrine magically remove the old values for manyToMany fields and set the new one,
- but for the oneToMany field it does not remove the old value but add the new one.

Is this a normal behaviour?

To work around I am DQLing to empty the oneToMany field target Entity for the mapped by model id and persisting new values

i.e Model: Rule has

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Tier", mappedBy="rule", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
* @JoinColumn(name="ruleId", referencedColumnName="ruleId")
* @var Tier[]
*/
public $tiers;
```

And in the Rule Mapper I am deleting all tiers before calling PERSIST to get UPDATE working:

```
public function resetTiers($ruleId)
{
$modelClass = "Tier";

$q = $this->doctrineEntityManager->createQuery("Delete from $modelClass m where m.rule =" . $ruleId);
$numDeleted = $q->execute();

return $numDeleted;
}
```

I don't mind doing this way as long as its OK and not introducing any bad practice.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this bit of Doctrine's documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html).

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.

And:

> OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.

Although:

> You can pick the owning side of a many-to-many association yourself.

So yes, it's normal behavior.

My guess is your `ManyToMany` relations are owned by your model (i.e. the Doctrine declaration you put in your property's comment says `inversedBy` and not `mappedBy`). Which would be why they're automatically updated (as per the doc linked above).

So either you start working on the other side's entities (namely `Tier`), or you trick the ORM by updating the other side's entities directly through your `Rule`'s accessors, probably something like:

```
public function setTiers($tiers) {
    foreach ($this->tiers as $tier) {
        $tier->setRule(null);
    }
    foreach ($tiers as $tier) {
        $tier->setRule($this);
    }
    if (is_array($tiers)) {
        //this wrapper is useful if you use syntaxes like
        //$someRule->getTiers()->add($someTier); which is usual if you use
        //an addTier(Tier $tier) method declared in Rule
        $tiers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($tiers);
    }
    $this->tiers = $tiers;
}
```

For the first option, working on other side's entities, just calling `$someTier->setRule($someRule)` will auto-update* `$someRule`'s `$tiers`.

*: auto-update should happen 1/ when you flush your mods and 2/ maybe you'll need to refresh the `$someRule` object (I mean the EM's `refresh` method).

All of this is "my guess", anyone feel free to correct, and OP feel free to give some feedback about how it went if you try this! ;)

Here is [some more doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html) about updating related entities, especially at the bottom of the page, section 6.14.1.

Hope this helps!